# Extract Observation from a Matrix

Tags: r, variables, select, matrix

I have a matrix (see above). I have the name of species and sub-species of plants in rows.

I would like to generate the same matrix with only the species and a matrix with only the sub-species.

The species in my initial matrix are composed of one word (`abelia`, `abis`) and sub-species contain always two words (`abies alba`, etc).

**How can i do that in R ?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the matrix is called `m`, you can try this:

```
species_rows <- lengths(strsplit(rownames(m)," "))==1 #split the rownames at whitespaces, retain only rows that are not split (vector of length 1).
species_mat <- m[species_rows,] #logical subsetting
subspecies_mat <- m[!species_rows,] #logical subsetting with negation
```

Hat tip to @akrun for pointing out that `lapply(..,length)` can be replaced by `lengths()`.

---

Or even simpler:

```
species_rows <- !grepl(" ",rownames(m)) # does the row.name NOT contain a whitespace? (TRUE / FALSE)
species_mat <- m[species_rows,]
subspecies_mat <- m[!species_rows,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, as suggested, it would have been good if you provided sample data to your question.

That said, I think you can do:

```
# First, generate data:
a <- matrix(sample(c(0, 1), 20), ncol = 4)
rownames(a) <- c("abies", 
                 "abies alba", 
                 "abies amabilis", 
                 "abies balsamea", 
                 "abies concolor")
```

Then, you can use `grep` to find which names contain an empty space:

```
sp <- grep(" ", rownames(a))
```

And finally, assign to new matrixes:

```
subspecies <- a[sp,]
species <- a[-sp,]
```

As a side note, I'd recommend working with a data frame instead of a matrix, and assigning the names to a variable, instead of rownames.